# Elastic search - PlainElastic.net manual json indexing

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, plainelastic.net

I would like to manually serialize an object to a string and index it by using PlainElastic.net.
I tried the followed:

```
Disk myDisk = Disks[1]; // Gets a Disk object from a dictionary

string command = Commands.Index("Album", "Music", myDisk.Id.ToString());
string json = "\"query\":{\"disk\": {\"album_id\":\"" + myDisk.albumId + "\",\"disk_id\":\"" + myDisk.Id + "\"}}";
OperationResult response = connection.Put(command, json);
```

However, I get an exception:

> "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." Afterwards,
>   I get the following exception:
>   {"error":"MapperParsingException[Malformed content, must start with an
>   object]","status":400}

Does anyone know how I should perform the indexing manually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, If you can suggest indexing using rest api and not through plainelastic.net, it is more than great :) However, I still need to write the index manually as I would like to index an object selected from my DB. 10x!

Comment: Your json is not valid. As the error says, it should start with an object - you're missing the start object '{' in the beginning of the JSON string.
and plainelastic uses the REST API. It's just a wrapper working against it.

Comment: Hi Rotem, first thank you! I fixed the Json and it worked. I know that the plainelastic is a wrapper which uses the rest api. What I meant is to replace the plainelastic.net usage with direct rest api calls. Anyway, thank you! it worked :)

Comment: You can issue the REST calls as just plain web requests, but I don't see a reason to do this - plainelastic is quite a nice library for that.